# xml to encrypted file?

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, file-io

Ok I know this has been covered a few times and I've read several post here on encryption algorithms and cryptography methods, etc.  However now my head is spinning and I'm still not sure what I need to do.  I have a set of data that is in xml format that I need to save to a file.

It's not terribly sensitive (no credit cards or anything) but I don't want users to be able to just open it as xml and make edits, etc.  I am not really worried about someone who is programming savvy hacking the format or decompiling to find keys, etc.

What I would like is a basic class that I can pass a string value (or XmlDocument but you can always call .OuterXml on that) and a key that I will hard code and get an encrypted value that I can write to a file.  I would then need to be able to read from a file on a different machine (client/customer machine) and decrypt back to the xml string to be processed by my program.  Again, the keys can be hard coded into the program so that they match in both locations...

Also I don't want to ask the user for a password or anything like that but I can hard code that into the program if necessary as well.

Can anyone point me to an easy way to do this?

Comment: This type of question (asking for sample code) is not well suited for SO

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can find good tutorials in the internet for this matter: I'll hint you to look for AES encryption in c#

Comment: Also, as a SO guideline, we do not include thanks in the Question

Comment: Will this link help you. you will need to further modify the sample code in the website to encrypt all xml elements http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry I'm not asking anyone to write the method for me, just trying to wrap my head around a system I haven't used before.  I found a few examples but none seemed to be exactly like this, and the sample code I found didn't work and I can't figure out why...

Comment: I believe the reason for the downvotes is that you do not show some sample code showing what you've tried so far. Anyway i provided an answer which i hope to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall here's what you need to do

1. Have a string as plain text (not encrypted)
2. Convert it to byte array (it's easier for cypher algorithms to work with byte[])
3. Have a cypher algorithm instance
4. Encrypt your plain text byte array with the cypher and your output is an encryped byte array
5. Store it in byte[] OR to store it in string use `Convert.ToBase64String()`

For some sample code:

For step 1

```
    private System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm GetAesKey()
    {
        byte[] symKey = RandomNextBytes();
        var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
        aes.Key = symKey;
        aes.IV = symKey;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        return aes;
     }
```

The above code creates a different aes key each time is invoked. `RandomNextBytes` is just a wrapper to create 16 bytes randomly. Note that .NET native random is not thread-safe so if you need the thread safety look for [Jon Skeet Thread-safe implementation](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx).

You'll probably want control If you want to have control over the AES key so you can have a `symKey` like this

```
byte[] symKey = new byte[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}
```

For the next steps wrap the cypher logic in a nice method

```
private string EncryptSymmetricToBase64(SymmetricAlgorithm symAlg, string plainText)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, symAlg.CreateEncryptor(symAlg.Key, symAlg.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
        {
            sw.Write(plainText);
        }
        string ciphered = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        return ciphered;
    }
}
```

The above code picks a plain text and a cypher algorithm. It then encrypts the string using a `CryptoStream`.
Before returning it converts the encrypted byte[] to a base64 string.

Note: A Base64 is an well-known algorithm to convert binary data to string and back.